# What is in your .gitignore when you use Spring Roo?

Tags: git, spring-roo, gitignore

I have some problem about merge conflict on target directory or *log.roo*. How do people solve this simple problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
log.roo
application.log*
.settings
.classpath
.project
target
.DS_Store
```

Comment: And the implicit answer would be: "by not adding those files to source control"

Comment: @madth3 although dry, it's an explicit and complete answer to the _title_ of the question (but not its _body_).

Answer (score 0):

If target is where your generated classes are located then that is the first folder to be added to gitignore